# Extract DriveId from FileName for Validation Function

Tags: vb.net

I have the following string which is a input test string to a DriveId validation function:

```
Cvmv1234 + { }  m v:::: \ \ \ ///Documents And Settings/Owner/My Documents
```

I only want the partial string: Cvmv1234 + { }  m v:::: \
The RegEx code is as follows:

```
DriveId = Regex.Match(Value, "\b.*:*[\/]{1}\b").ToString
```

I tried a number of modifications to the RegEx pattern but *I always get the entire input string*.  Please advise as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Jerry B

Comment: Are you saying that you want the string up to and including the first "\", like `yourString.Substring(0, yourString.IndexOf("\") + 1)`?

Comment: If so, then the regex `(.*?\\)` should work.

Comment: Hi Andrew    Yes, the beginning of the string up to the first \ OR /.

According to your answer, I am making the RegEx more complicated than it has to be.

Thanks to you, and using your solution in Expresso, I now have it.  The regex pattern to get 2 parts is now:
  
    (.*?[\\/]{1})(.*) 

Again, thanks for the help.  I really appreciated it.

Jerry B

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the beginning of the string up to the first \ OR /.

According to your answer, I am making the RegEx more complicated than it has to be.

Thanks to you, and using your solution in Expresso, I now have it.  The regex pattern to get 2 parts is now:

```
(.*?[\\/]{1})(.*)
```

Again, thanks for the help.  I really appreciated it.

Jerry B